# Solve system of equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$$\sin(x+y)+1.6x=0$$

$$x^2+y^2=-1$$

Can this system be solved? Please help me with it. I managed to make graphs of it but can't get it solved without graph.

Graph:
[image]

Comment: in which domain is that to be solve?

Comment: I think no imaginary numbers only. I will need to use Newton method after solution to find intersection.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: For what real $x$ and $y$ will we have $$x^2+y^2=-1,$$ if any?

Answer (score 1):

If the domain is real number no square numbers sum will be negative.

So no x and y satisfy the equation

Answer (score 1):

since we have for all real numbers $x^2+y^2\geq 0>-1$ we get no real solutions for this system.
you can only plug $y=\sqrt{-x^2-1}$ or $y=-\sqrt{-x^2-1}$ in your equation.

Comment: So it is not possible to use Newton method with this system? Or can we choose any x and y to start with? Because I have a graph.

Comment: it is also possible to use the newton method for complex numbers, or is a typo in your system?

Comment: And what would be solution if we will use complex?

Answer (score -1):

Solved:
$$sin(x+y)+1.6x=0$$
$$x^2+y^2=-1$$ 

$$y=√(|-x^2-1|)$$

$$ sin(x+√(|-x^2-1|)+1.6*x=0$$

**x=-0.393536**

$$ y=√(|0.393536^2-1|)$$

**y=0.91931**

Looking at the graph it seems these are correct values.
Thank you, especially Dr. Sonnhard Graubner.

Comment: Your graph is incorrect. The values of $x$ and $y$ that you found are approximate solutions to $x^2+y^2=1,$ ***not*** to $x^2+y^2=-1.$ From $y^2=-x^2-1,$ we can conclude that $|y|=\sqrt{-x^2-1},$ ***not*** that $y=\sqrt{|-x^2-1|}.$

Comment: Approximate values is what I need because later I will find them as accurate as needed according to error value with Newton method. If there is no x and y values which correspondent to $$x^2+y^2=−1$$ then I will calculate with 1 instead because work has to be done anyway.. Maybe this was a mistake made when filling equations.